# How can I install AMD Radeon drivers in my laptop?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

The closest thing I've found for Ubuntu 16.10 GNOME is Oibaf's drivers, and I don't know how to install them

I did:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mesa
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I closed the dist upgrade in the middle cause I thought it would upgrade me to the latest version that is 17.10, but I want to stay at 16.10 for now (not enough internet)

But I still can't see my Graphics card listed in **system details**.